# Array initialised with all elements as zero is spitting out random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, element

So for my assignment I have to create a calculator that works with big integers up to 256 characters in length. The current part of the assignment I'm up to is getting it work with larger numbers after starting with smaller ones. I have an array that gets filled with numbers and works perfectly fine with 10 numbers in all of my tests. I changed the value of DIGITS to 256 from 10 and upon getting strange numbers I investigated with some cout's and it turns out that if I add 00000 + 00000 (can be any sized numbers or any digits, I chose these as it's simple to sift through as everything should be zero in all array elements) I get a very strange answer

(2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000180000000000000020000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000).

I checked each array element and some of the elements will be filled with a random number. My array is initialised with

`digits_[DIGITS] = { 0 };` have also tried a for loop to set array elements to zero with the same results.

DIGITS is set in the header file as 256

A pattern I have noticed is that in both arrays n1 & n2 which are supposed to be two different numbers being added or subtracted etc. are filled with the SAME number on that particular element. So n1[81] and n2[81] will both be set to 9 for some reason. However this changes everytime the program is compiled and ran.

Full code below (The couts in the methods are just for me to assess the arrays for these errors)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Bigint.h"

using namespace std;

Bigint::Bigint()
{
        digits_[DIGITS] = { 0 };

}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Bigint& n)
{
    string s = "";
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = DIGITS - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(n.digits_[i] > 0) {
            found = true;
        }
        if(n.digits_[i] != 0 || found == true) {
            s += char(n.digits_[i] + '0');
        }
    }
    if (s == "") {
        s = "0";
    }
    return out << s;
}

istream& operator>> (istream& in, Bigint& n)
{
    string s;
    if (in >> s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < DIGITS; ++i) {
            n.digits_[i] = s[s.length() - 1 - i] - '0';
        }
    }
    return in;
}

Bigint operator+ (const Bigint& n1, const Bigint& n2)
{
    Bigint ret;
    int cur_carry = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < DIGITS; ++i) {
        int n1_digit = n1.get(i);
        int n2_digit = n2.get(i);
        if(n1_digit < 0 || n1_digit > 9) {
            n1_digit = 0;
        }
        if(n2_digit < 0 || n2_digit > 9) {
            n2_digit = 0;
        }
        printf("n1 : %d\n", n1_digit);
        printf("n2 : %d\n", n2_digit);
        int sum = n1_digit + n2_digit + cur_carry;
        cout << "sum : " << sum << endl;
        cur_carry = Bigint::getCarry(sum);
        cout << "new carry : " << cur_carry << endl;
        ret.set(i, Bigint::getDigitValue(sum));
        cout << "Set : " << i << "," << Bigint::getDigitValue(sum) << endl;
    }
    return ret;
}

Bigint operator- (const Bigint& n1, const Bigint& n2)
{
    Bigint ret;
    //Should only ever have a max value of 1, used to borrow values from next digit column of bigint
    int borrowed = 0;
    //Stores final value to subtract from
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < DIGITS; --i) {
        int n1_digit = n1.get(i);
        int n2_digit = n2.get(i);
        if(n1_digit < 0 || n1_digit > 9) {
            n1_digit = 0;
        }
        if(n2_digit < 0 || n2_digit > 9) {
            n2_digit = 0;
        }


        //Ensure we take into account borrowed values from previous digit subtractions
        temp = n1_digit - borrowed;
        //Reset borrowed
        borrowed = 0;
        //If n1 digit value < n2 digit value we need to borrow a 10 from next digit column
        if(temp < n2_digit) {
            //Borrow 10 and increment borrowed for next computation
            temp = n1_digit + 10;
            borrowed++;
        }
        //Store value
        ret.set(i, temp - n2_digit);
    }
    return ret;
}

Bigint operator* (const Bigint& n1, const Bigint& n2)
{
    return n1; // Only correct when n2 equals 1.
}

Bigint operator/ (const Bigint& n1, const Bigint& n2)
{
    return n1; // Only correct when n2 equals 1.
}


int Bigint::get(int pos) const {
    int ret = digits_[pos];
    return ret;
}

void Bigint::set(int pos, int val) {
    this->digits_[pos] = val;
}

int Bigint::getCarry(int val) {
    return val/10;
}

int Bigint::getDigitValue(int val) {
    return val % 10;
}
```

Header file:

```
#ifndef BIGINT_H_
#define BIGINT_H_

#define DIGITS 256

class Bigint
{
  public:

    /**
     * Creates a Bigint initialised to 0.
     */
    Bigint();

    /**
     * Inserts n into stream or extracts n from stream.
     */
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Bigint& n);
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in, Bigint& n);

    /**
     * Returns the sum, difference, product, or quotient of n1 and n2.
     */
    friend Bigint operator+ (const Bigint& n1, const Bigint& n2);
    friend Bigint operator- (const Bigint& n1, const Bigint& n2);
    friend Bigint operator* (const Bigint& n1, const Bigint& n2);
    friend Bigint operator/ (const Bigint& n1, const Bigint& n2);

    int get(int pos) const;
    void set(int pos, int val);

    static int getCarry(int val);
    static int getDigitValue(int val);

  private:
    int digits_[DIGITS];
};

#endif // BIGINT_H_
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Bigint.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    Bigint n1, n2;
    char op;

    while (cin >> n1 >> op >> n2) {
        switch (op) {
        case '+' :
            cout << n1 + n2 << endl;
            break;
        case '-' :
            cout << n1 - n2 << endl;
            break;
        case '*' :
            cout << n1 * n2 << endl;
            break;
        case '/' :
            cout << n1 / n2 << endl;
            break;
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to show us [MCVE]. Without it, your descriptions are of little relevance, since what you're describing may be caused my a number of things.

Comment: @Fureeish Okay, apologies, have added the code for the class I'm referring to

Comment: Narrow it down please. One of the three key words there is "minimal". We don't have time to do the first few steps of debugging on every post here!

Comment: Also don't modify the question to incorporate the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your constructor:

```
Bigint::Bigint()
{
        digits_[DIGITS] = { 0 };

}
```

The syntax `digits_[DIGITS] = { 0 };` here does not initialise all the elements of `digits_` to `0`. It accesses the *`DIGITS`-th* element (one past the end - this is index out of bounds) and sets it do `0`. This is *undefined behaviour* and a program that exhibits one may behave in any way - expected or unexpected.

The fix is quite easy. The very same syntax (`digits_[DIGITS] = { 0 };`) *can* be used to initialize all the elements to `0`, but it must be used in the *declaration*. So, in order to fix the issue you must:

1. get rid of the above constructor
2. replace `int digits_[DIGITS];` in your **header file** with `int digits_[DIGITS] = {0};`.

*EDIT*:

It appears that you had another bug - in your `operator >>`. The line:

```
n.digits_[i] = s[s.length() - 1 - i] - '0';
```

also invokes *undefined behaviour* unless the `length()` of `s` is exactly `DIGITS`. When you input `00000`, `s.length() == 5`. Now, your `i` range is from `0` to `DIGITS` (`255`). What happens when, let's say, `i == 100`? The following gets executed:

```
n.digits_[100] = s[-96] - '0';
```

And this is not what we want. You need to add a guard for that. For example:

```
n.digits_[i] = i < s.length() ? s[s.length() - 1 - i] - '0' : 0;
```

Comment: I just tested this and still get the same result. I was also getting the same result when using a for loop to initialize each element to 0.

Comment: @Cloppy Did you get rid of the constructor that exhibited *undefined behaviour*?

Comment: I just noticed that if I do what you just said AND ALSO run the following for loop for (int i = DIGITS-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        digits_[i] = 0;
    }
it gives a different result " 800000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008000000180000000000000020000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 "

Comment: Yes I did get rid of the constructor that exhibited undefined behaviour and still got the same result of the long number that starts with a 2. But as said in this previous comment above this, when applying both your initialiser in the header AND the for loop, I somehow get a different number

Comment: I am compiling with g++ in ubuntu WSL @Fureeish

Comment: I meant how are you running the code in regard to how does your `main()` look like. I just tested `Bigint n1, n2;
    cin >> n1 >> n2;
    cout << (n1 + n2);` and it seems to work. If it gives you different results, we may need to inspect for further bugs in your code. Did you use a debugger to check *when* those unexpected numbers appear in your code?

Comment: I use `while (cin >> n1 >> op >> n2) {
        switch (op) {
        case '+' :
            cout << n1 + n2 << endl;
            break;
        case '-' :
            cout << n1 - n2 << endl;
            break;
        case '*' :
            cout << n1 * n2 << endl;
            break;
        case '/' :
            cout << n1 / n2 << endl;
            break;
        }`

Comment: @Cloppy can you share your **current** code via, for example, [pastebin](www.pastebin.com) (please make sure to put everything in one file)?

Comment: I'm not too sure how to use that, but I will add the code for main.cpp in the main post above, those 3 sets of code are the entire project

Comment: @Cloppy you **still** have your *undefined-behaviour-invoking* constructor. Please get rid of it and check whether the code executed correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't update that bit of code on the post above since you told me to, but Ihave tested with out it, and still does not work. I have now updated, so everything above in the post is how the program is now. and still does not work in the same way

Comment: @Cloppy I've spotted another bug in your program - please see the edit.

Comment: @Cloppy if the answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it so the future visitors who may come across the same problem will know that this indeed is the solution.